# Finding the median value of an RGB image in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

Is there any easy way of finding the median value of a RGB image in OpenCV using C? 
In MATLAB we can just extract the arrays corresponding to the three channels and compute median values for each of the arrays by `median(median(array))`. Finally, the median value of these three medians (for three channels) can be calculated for the final median value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the matrix to a histogram via the [`calcHist`](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html) function (once for each channel), then calculate the median for a given channel by using the function available [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/20522/get-the-median-added-to-mean-and-std-value/).

Note: I have not tested that linked code, but it should at least give you an idea of how to get started.

Comment: Is there any way you can write down the OpenCV C code using `cvCalcHist`? The parameters are confusing me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Let's say I have an RGB image `img`, which I split into three channels as you said using `cvSplit(img, B, G, R, NULL)`. Then I want to use `cvCalcHist` to calculate the histogram of R, G, B arrays. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: anyone else finding their way to this question might be interested in my implementation of a cv::median function for single channels: https://gist.github.com/heisters/9cd68181397fbd35031b

Comment: Can you complete the answer here so that people don't have to open your link? By the way, I cannot access it.